# Manual controller registration in ASP.NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to override ASP.NET Core's default registration for a certain controller.

I've tried the below, but it resolves `MyController` from the automatic registration.

```
services.AddTransient((provider) => new MyController(...));
```

How can I override this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, controllers are resolved using *type activation*, which boils down to the framework using an equivalent of `Activator.CreateInstance` to create controller instances. The dependencies for these controllers are sourced from the DI container, but the controller itself isn't.

Fortunately, there's a way to get the framework to use DI for the controllers too, using [`AddControllersAsServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's an example (in `ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

Comment: If we are on ASP.NET 3+, I think the equivalent is `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddControllersAsServices()` or similar

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Yeah, that's right. I think you can still use `AddMvc`, but those other methods are recommended in the docs, etc.